# HttpClient WebException not caught

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin

I have following code (Xamarin.iOS)

```
try
{
    httpResult = await _httpClient.GetAsync( uri, cts.Token ).ConfigureAwait( false );
    ...
}
catch ( System.Net.WebException ex )
{
    Console.WriteLine( "!Web exception outer uri :" + URI + " message: " + ex.Message);
}
catch ( Exception ex )
{
    var isWebException = ex is System.Net.WebException; // ----> TRUE ???
}
```

Sometimes WebException is not caught by WebException block, but in general exception block (isWebException = true). 
How can this be true?